# Access $view object when using AJAX on a View

Tags: ajax, drupal, view

When using views without Ajax, it's easy to access the $view->result array using hook_views_pre_render(). But how can I access the $view object if I'm using Ajax to filter my view?

I want to use to result in different Javascripts and forms, therefore the best solution would be to put $view->result in the Drupal.settings object.

Is this possible? I've found hook_ajax_data_alter() but I don't know how to use it, or if it's the right way to go.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've found a somewhat good looking solution.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_ajax_data_alter().
 */
function request_ajax_data_alter(&$object, &$type, &$view) {
  $array = FALSE;
  // Detect whether the data being altered is an array.
  if (is_array($object)) {
    $object = (object) $object;
    $array = TRUE;
  }
  $object->scripts = $extra['scripts'];
  $object->css = $extra['css'];
  if (!isset($object->__callbacks)) {
    $object->__callbacks = array();
  }

  // Add the view result to the object.
  $object->view_result = $view->result;

  // Set the custom event as a callback.
  $object->__callbacks[] = 'Drupal.request.saveResult';

  // Cast back to an array if necessary.
  if ($array) {
    $object = (array) $object;
  }
}
```

I've simply added the $view->result to the $object, and added my custom callback, which adds $view->result to the Drupal.settings object.

I tried to add a callback directly to the $view object, but didn't succeed, so this will do for now.

Please let me know if there's a better way to do this =)

Comment: I believe you're looking for hook_views_ajax_data_alter: http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_ajax_data_alter/7